# Retrieve Code from App on the APP Store

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store, recovery

I have had my Mac stolen but even worse they stole my Apple Time Machine. I have an App available on the App Store, is there anyway I can retireve the source code so that I can release updates/bug fixes ? I know I should have backued up in the cloud, lesson learned !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. When you upload your app to the store, the code is compiled into a binary. There is no way to retrieve your code because it is not there.

Comment: The sets can be recovered.